# Form data serialized with JSON.stringify cannot be accessed from the $_POST variable

Tags: javascript, php, json, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have created a React application from which I am calling my server built on PHP.

The following is how I call my PHP file:

```js
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ name, username, password }),
};
console.log(requestOptions);

fetch('http://localhost/crud/requests/signup.php', requestOptions)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Here is what I have in the PHP file:

```php
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
  // do something
}
```

When I print the `$_POST` variable, I get an empty array.  Even the `$_RESPONSE` is empty.

But when I tried to print the input stream like this:

```php
print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Everything seems to be fine. Can anyone explain why does this happen?
I tried to read it in the documentation & looked up on some forums and blogs but wasn't satisfied with the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP’s built-in form support is only able to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` forms and `multipart/form-data` forms.  What you are actually sending is a JSON-serialized object, with the incorrect MIME type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

To *actually* send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form, use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead of `JSON.stringify`:

```js
fetch('http://localhost/crud/requests/signup.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new URLSearchParams({ name, username, password }),
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

There is no need to set `Content-Type` explicitly in this case: [the browser will do that automatically](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract).  To send a `multipart/form-data` payload (which you may need to do if you want to upload larger files), use a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object instead.

If you want to send JSON after all, you should send it with the correct MIME type in the header, `application/json`.  On the PHP side, you will be resigned to parsing the payload manually using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/json_decode).